# Possible to set SQL Server Remote Query Timeout per Query for Linked Server calls?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

For linked servers, I see how it is possible to change the "remote query timeout" configuration to hint a call to a linked server should complete or rollback within the specific timeout value.  This appears to work across the SQL Server engine--is it possible to change the hint within a stored procedure, so that a specific stored procedure could run longer if needs to, but all other non-hinted SPROCs would timeout quicker if they run long?

Linked Query Timeout is discussed here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314530

Example code to set it to timeout in 3 seconds is here:

```
sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 3       
go 
reconfigure with override 
go
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really advisable to change it within a stored procedure.  [`remote query timeout` is a global server setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189040.aspx) when altered with `sp_configure`, so changing it in a stored procedure affects all remote queries for all linked servers on the server.

Additionally, executing `sp_configure` requires the `ALTER SETTINGS` server permission, which typically only `sysadmin` and `serveradmin` have.  Granting these permissions to a data access account would be a security concern since they could potentially take your server down with `sp_configure` commands.

What I would suggest is creating a second linked server with a different name that you would use with just this one stored procedure.  You can, in SSMS, configure a [query timeout for each individual linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  Adding a second linked server would enable you to query the same server with different linked server client settings.  You might need to create a DNS CNAME to accomplish this if you're using plain SQL Server Linked Servers.